# Flyway-node library throwing the following error: end of central directory record signature not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, flyway

I am trying to migrate my sql files using the following code

```
 const flywayApi = new Flyway(flywayConfig)
    flywayApi.migrate().then(response => {
        if (!response.success) {
            // Handle failure case
            console.log(`Unable to execute migrate command. Error: ${response.error.errorCode}`);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Database migration successful!');
            // Handle response
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`Unable to execute migrate command. Error: ${err}`);
    })
```

config file is the following

```
    module.exports = function() {
    return {
        flywayArgs: {
            url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gtjdb',
            schemas: 'public',
            locations: 'filesystem:migration/master',
            user: 'postgres',
            password: 'admin',
            sqlMigrationSuffixes: '.pgsql',
            baselineOnMigrate: true,
            baselineVersion:"0"
        },
        // Use to configure environment variables used by flyway
        env: {
            JAVA_ARGS: '-Djava.util.logging.config.file=./conf/logging.properties',
        },
        version: '6.3.2', // optional, empty or missing will download the latest
        mavenPlugins: [{ // optional, use to add any plugins (ie. logging)
            groupId: 'org.slf4j',
            artifactId: 'slf4j-api',
            version: '1.7.25',
            // This can be a specifc url to download that may be different then the auto generated url.
            downloadUrl: 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar',
        }, {
            groupId: 'org.slf4j',
            artifactId: 'slf4j-jdk14',
            version: '1.7.25'
        }],
        downloads: {
            storageDirectory: '/var/test', // optional, the specific directory to store the flyway downloaded files. The directory must be writable by the node app process' user.
            expirationTimeInMs: -1, // optional, -1 will never check for updates, defaults to 1 day.
        }
    };
};
```

folder tree is the following

[image]

I can't figure out the issue here